# How to change comments characters in assembly mode

Tags: characters

I am editing `.s` files whit an assembly-to-binary translator that does not accept `;` as a comment delimiter but accept C like comments (namely `//` and `/* ... */`).

I tried to modify `comment-start` variable locally using `set-variable` command but it does not matches any `comment-start`. When I display the variable within a `.s` (emacs correctly indicate Assembler mode) it says `;` locally and `nil` globaly (wtf ??).

For the `asm-comment-char` variable, it says value is 59 which corresponds to the ascii code for `;` but when I tried to set it, for example to `//`, it says it does not match type character of the variable. So I tried to set it to 047047 which is supposed to be the ascii code for `//` but my comment's keys still give `;` or `;;`.

So what can i do ? Which one of these variables control the comments characters in assembly mode ?

Comment: `asm-comment-char` does and as you note, it's a single char. That's a limitation that should probably be lifted. I would suggest you consider [submitting a bug report](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bugs.html#Bugs)